# Devise getting 401 unauthorized right after sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

```
Rails 4.2, Ruby 2.2.0, Devise 3.5.7
```

I have an `Admin` model. In ideal case after sign in, it should be redirected to homepage. But in my case, it is signing in successfully, but while redirecting, somehow authentication fails, causing it to redirect to the sign in page again.

The controller which gets called is:

```
Class Admin::DashboardsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_admin!
  before_filter :authorize

  def show

  end

end
```

In first view, I thought it is a problem with `authorize` method. But code never reaches it.
`authenticate_admin!` is a devise method. And I don't know if there is a point in debugging.

Surprisingly it works on local, but results in `401 Unauthorized` after deploying.

Logs

[image]

Comment: What does the `log` say?

Comment: Try `before_action :authorize` or `beofre_filter :authenticate_admin!` I can't remember exactly, but in some version of rails they replaced `before_filter` with `before_action`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @jedi before_action is new name for before_filter

Comment: @TomLord updated log

Comment: @sawa  Why not working? Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Have you tried what I said?

Comment: Do you have your own custom Devise controllers or you use the default ones?

Comment: I have defined SessionsController and for now each method calls super.

Comment: @jedi before_filter -->  before_action not worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the application is fine. It has to do something with your server configurations. Something might be missing.

As you said it is working locally, there might be something that you changed in your configurations for the server, that might be causing the problem. Check your config files, `application.rb` or any other subdomain files that you might be using.

Comment: I agree. Also check your admin model permissions on the server as it seems he does not have proper permissions there.

Comment: It was a problem with sub-domain routing. I still have no idea from where it is getting called. It is meta programming, so difficult to find. Not a problem with permissions.